# Whirlpool gas oven not staying lit

Tags: gas, oven

I have a whirlpool gas range model #wfg5050bw.  It is only 3 yrs old.  My oven quit working a few weeks ago.  After internet searching decided to replace the ignitor.  I did that  which also involved splicing the old connector to the new ignitor, since the connectors were different.  I'm still having the same issue.  Sometimes the oven will light but it won't stay lit.  When I push the button on the control board to turn the oven on I hear a click.  Then shortly thereafter a second click.  When this happens the oven won't light at all.  The times it does light, when I hear that 2nd click is when it shuts off.
Is it the control board that needs replacing?

Comment: Might be a flame sensor.  If sensor gets dirty it does not see the flame and cuts off the gas so you don't get poisoned.

Comment: @crip659  Gotta agree, sounds like a flame sensor to me as well.

Comment: Additional information...sometimes it will not light at all.  I can push the touch pad and I hear the normal "click".  Within a couple of seconds I hear another "click" and that's when it won't light at all.